# How to get a keyframe file from a video for subtitling

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitle

I use Aegisub for subtitling, but the keyframes read by the program are sometimes incorrect, so I need an external keyframe file (also called a pass file). If what I mean is not clear, it is well explained on Aegisub manual [here](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/Video/#keyframes). Accepted formats are .pass, .stats, .txt and .log.

In Windows I managed to do that through scxvid.exe and ffmpeg.exe following the method explained in [this subtitling guide](http://doki.co/support/doki-timing-guide/) (section 3). How can I do this in Ubuntu? Both terminal and GUI are ok.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is Aegisub simply not reading the keyframe data properly from these problem inputs? Or are the keyframes being reported properly but just not conducive for subtitle timing? If the first case, then you can use `ffprobe` to create a keyframe file. If the second, then you can use `ffmpeg` to generate a pass log. (I know almost nothing about fansubbing.)

Comment: Aegisub has its own internal way of reading keyframes directly from the video file, but it's not always precise. The Aegisub manual itself says "Even if keyframes can be read from the file it is sometimes useful to override them with external keyframes."